# Book to learn about Geometric Proofs in order to get through Kiselev's Planimetry

Tags: geometry, reference-request, education

Some quick background: I am 28 yo, have been out of school for a while, but active in learning to code, and do a lot of research whenever i hit a roadblock, mainly math etc. I plan to go back to school and finally graduate, then maybe start a SoftEng. program. I do not want to leave my education up to our horrible system, since I've done only basic math up to the graduation year, which makes me sick.

I found a roadmap [from a poster on Quora](https://www.quora.com/If-you-had-to-teach-yourself-math-from-basic-algebra-to-high-level-mathematics-what-would-be-your-strategy)
, who gave a list:

- Geometry
- Algebra II
- Pre-Calculus/Trigonometry etc.

and says that geometry is great because one gets a good background in proofs.
Now, sadly, all i've seen in school, is basic geometry, basic formulas etc, no proofs or derivations whatsoever. Up to a few days ago I thought that's what geometry was. Not being a naive person, I delved into the 1st chapter of Kiselev's book, thought it was a great, super-condensed read, then the questions baffled me. I am supposed to proof this stuff, that seems logic to me!?
Allthough it seemed simple at the first look of the questions, I found out I was sincerely lost.

Now I feel super alienated, but want to start from scratch all the way up.

**Could you please refer me a good resource or some sort of roadmap in order to get proficient at proofs and the like**.

I want to start with a 'clean slate' in math, because I've hated it in school, and now i'm falling in love with it.

I know I can learn 'anything', but judging the 'niveau' of the book, I feel really scared now, and hope I can make up for the lost time and education.

I hope somebody can relate, Thank you very much for your time!!!

Comment: A recommended, freely available text:
https://ia800303.us.archive.org/17/items/Geometry1/13Geometry1.pdf

Comment: Thank you for that resource, seems to be a very good read!

Answer (score 0):

Of course one way to learn math is to do math.

But, in your situation, you might be better off starting not with a Math book but with a book about how to math.

Like  *How to Prove it* by DJ Velleman

Comment: Thank you for posting that book! I had a go at it for a few hours, really great to begin looking at this matter in a more logical way, and learning how to read and express logic in words or some other set of expressions.